# PDO query not executing in while loop

Tags: php, pdo

I am tyring to use PDO to retrieve data from a database.

I can retrieve 'NAME' during the first iteration but not after the 2nd iteration.

my code is as follows:-

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $id = $row["ID"];
   $query = "SELECT NAME FROM Style_Master WHERE ID=$id";
   $stmt = $db->query($query);
   $style_name = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["NAME"];
   echo $style_name; // for first id name is displayed but for next id onwards no style name is displayed.
}
```

Comment: inside while block, remove everything and put this: `echo $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["ID"];` tell me what you got?

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that you have a piece of code like this

```
$queryA = "SELECT id, somethingelse FROM somewhere";

$stmt = $db->query($queryA);
```

Before the while loop.
At first iteration you fetch the first record resulting from *queryA*

After you re-assign the same variable $stmt with other records coming from

```
$query = "SELECT NAME FROM Style_Master WHERE ID=$id";
```

It happens that at second iteration (assuming there are many NAMEs with same ID otherwise the loop ends), you look for a field "id" into the result-set of query you used to find "name".
So you iterate the query using id=*null*

Comment: You are not paying attention. What do you think happens when you run this code:

`$test = true;

while($test) {
  echo "Loop running";
  $test = false;
}`

Do you think the loop will keep running or stop after running once?

Comment: @farooqaaa In your example the loop will run once imho.

Comment: @PaoloDiMaio That is the point I was making. He reassigned the `$stmt` variable and expected the loop to run.

Answer (score 0):

$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["NAME"]; ?

```
  $style_name = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["NAME"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is related with the variable scope.

When you do something like this: (see the comments)

```
<?php
$stmt = 10;
while (0 < $stmt){
  // here, I am acessing the outside varialbe $stmt
  echo "{$stmt}<br>"; // 10 will be printed
  $stmt = 0; // I am modifying the outside variable.  
  $stmt--; here the outside variable will be -1
  echo "{$stmt}<br>"; // will print -1. And loop will end
}
```

With this, your code should be like this:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $id = $row["ID"];
   $query = "SELECT NAME FROM Style_Master WHERE ID=$id";
   $stmt2 = $db->query($query); 
   $style_name = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["NAME"];
   echo $style_name; // for first id name is displayed but for next id onwards no style name is displayed.
}
```

This:

```
$stmt2 = $db->query($query);
```

Because the outside variable `$stmt` should not be modified inside your loop.
When you do :

```
$stmt = $db->query($query);
```

You are modifying the outside variable and with that, you are changing your loop behavior.

Comment: @PradeepSanku update your question to show how do you updated your code, pls